# Can lazy evaluation be implemented by a monadic type?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I'm currently studying lazy evaluation in conjunction with monads in Javascript and what use cases may evolve from these. So I tried to implement a lazy type, which implements the functor/monad type class. The corresponding constructor is meant to be lazy in its arguments and in its result. Here is what I came up with:

```js
// a lazy type

// (() -> a) -> () -> b
const Lazy = thunk => () => thunk();

// (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Lazy a -> b
Lazy.fold = f => acc => tx => f(acc) (tx());

// (a -> b) -> Lazy a -> Lazy b
Lazy.map = f => tx => Lazy(() => f(tx()));

// Lazy (a -> b) -> Lazy a -> Lazy b
Lazy.ap = tf => tx => Lazy(() => tf() (tx()));

Lazy.of = Lazy;

// Lazy (Lazy a) -> Lazy a
Lazy.join = ttx => ttx();

// (a -> Lazy b) -> Lazy a -> Lazy b
Lazy.chain = ft => tx => Lazy.join(Lazy.map(ft) (tx));

// recursive bind (or chain in Javascript)

// Number -> (a -> b) -> a -> Lazy b
const repeat = n => f => x => {
  const aux = m => y => m === 0
   ? Lazy(() => y)
   : Lazy.chain(aux(m - 1)) (Lazy(() => f(y)));

  return aux(n) (x);
};

// impure function to observe the computation

const inc = x => (console.log(++x), x);

// and run

console.log(repeat(5) (inc) (0)); // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, () => thunk()
```

Now this evidently makes no sense, since the action sequence isn't lazy at all. `Lazy.join` simply triggers the evaluation prematurely. Hence, the following questions have emerged:

- are sequences of monadic actions in Haskell always eagerly evaluated?
- is lazy evaluation an effect that cannot be implemented by a monad in a strictly evaluated language?

I am not even sure if my research makes any sense, so feel free to vote for closing this question.

Comment: I'd love some explanation of all these shorthand variable names

Comment: `join` should be `tx => Lazy(tx())`

Comment: This looks a lot like the Continuation monad - but harder to thread data thru the computation

Comment: @evolutionxbox Which specifically? `t` probably stands for thunk, `f` for function, and `x` is just an x.

Comment: @Bergi so tx is "thunk of x" and tf is "thunk function"?

Comment: @evolutionxbox exactly. Or with "for" as joiner.

Comment: @Bergi and `() -> a` is a function signature?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `tx` = fancy type, `ft` = function that returns a fancy type, fancy type = a type that represents a context with a value (the context of `Lazy` is lazy evaluation and thunks respectively. `() -> a` is the signature of a thunk, at least in Javascript)

Comment: @naomik exactly, great that you saw it too (`Lazy.join`)!

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but I like to think in "reverse" from it seems like how you are.  Not "can laziness be implemented by a monad?" but "is this thunk type I made which models laziness a monad? / what algebraic structure does it have?"  Start with the type and discover the structure.

Comment: I think a lot of your type signatures would make more sense if you used `Lazy a` instead of `(() -> a)`

Comment: @luqui This kind of implicit knowledge is frequently very helpful, thanks. I guess I've committed the common mistake (of a rookie) of trying to wrap each effect into a monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "implementing lazy evaluation".  You can certainly make a "Delay" type and it will be a monad. But normally we think of a function with type `A -> State S B` as being a "stateful function from `A` to `B`". With something like `A -> Delay B`, it seems that for the argument `A` we've already "forced" it.  It seems like we'd really want something more like `Delay A -> Delay B`.

It turns out that there are multiple ways of converting an expression to monadic style.  A call-by-value way, which is the usual way, and a call-by-name way.  This is discussed by Phil Wadler in his 1992 paper [Comprehending Monads](https://doi.org/10.1145/91556.91592) ([PDF](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/WadlerMonads.pdf)). Not surprisingly, these are related to a similar fact that there are two translations into continuation-passing style (CPS): a call-by-value one and a call-by-name one. Indeed, these are exactly the call-by-value/-name monadic style translations just with the continuation monad.  The purpose of CPS was to separate the order of evaluation of a target, implementation language from the order of evaluation of the source language. If you use the call-by-value CPS transform to implement a source language, it will have call-by-value semantics regardless of what the evaluation order of the target language is.  Similarly, if you use the call-by-name CPS transform, you will likewise get call-by-name semantics regardless of the evaluation order of the target language.

I don't know exactly how things would play out when using a call-by-value translation with a `Delay` monad, but I suspect it will often be "just a bit" off and "correcting" it will move more towards a call-by-name translation.

Comment: _...it will move more towards a call-by-name translation._ You're absolutely right! When you have a monadic computation based on the `Delay` type and inject an expression into the monad, this expression is immediately evaluated, because for the initial computation step it isn't wrapped in a thunk yet (`const of = x => Delay(() => x)` where `x` is evaluated immediately in JS). So indeed it is "just a bit" off and "correcting".

Answer (score 1):

> this evidently makes no sense, since the action sequence isn't lazy at all. `Lazy.join` simply triggers the evaluation prematurely

Yes. So just don't do that:

```
// (() -> (() -> a)) -> (() -> a)
Lazy.join = ttx => Lazy(() => ttx()());
//                         ^^ this function prevents `ttx` from being evaluated immediately
```

(though you can, and possible should for performance reasons, drop the `Lazy` wrapper or make `Lazy = id`)

> are sequences of monadic actions in Haskell always eagerly evaluated?

No, Haskell doesn't evaluate anything until you tell it to do. Monads are no exception, they work like any other data type.

> is lazy evaluation an effect that cannot be implemented by a monad in a strictly evaluated language?

No, it works perfectly fine.

However, you might want to notice that you haven't yet implemented [lazy implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) completely, which also implies sharing of results instead of re-evaluation. This does require mutability though, and works well only if the evaluated functions are pure.

Comment: Ya, `join` has to be lazy too.

Comment: "_sharing of results_" makes absolutely sense. I will look at this more closely. You saved my day again, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: "_drop the `Lazy` wrapper_" - isn't a monad just a type constraint, i.e. needs a type to exist? What type would this be then, if I drop my `(() -> a) -> (() -> b)`? Simply the function type?

Comment: @ftor I meant to call to the `Lazy` function, not the type wrapper (which is more like an alias even in your case, given `Lazy == id`). You might have more interesting results with `const Lazy = thunk => ({run: thunk});`

Comment: `{runX :: Type}` in Haskell is just a convenient way to retrieve the underlying value without having to explicitly define a global function. In Javascript you can just get the value, but maybe the calling code is more clear with `.runLazy`. I think it's funny that people define all these `.getX` and `.runY` in Javascript, although they are not in the global namespace. If they were merely `.run`/`.get` then one could define correpsonding generic getters and write `run(tf)` or `get(tx)` instead of `tf.runLazy()` or `tx.getConst()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Playing around**

Your question is fun and I haven't yet explored such a monad so I wanted to play around with it.

As Bergi points out, there's no need for the additional thunk wrapper in your data constructor – ie, `Lazy` expects its argument to be a thunk already.

Your `join` was broken – as counter-intuitive as it might seem, you have to make sure you wrap the unwrapping process! Think of it as adding one wrapper, but removing two; you still remove one layer of nesting, which achieves the intended result

Your monadic `return` (or `of` in this case) is also broken; `return` is not always the same as your data constructor – ie `Lazy.of(2)` should be equivalent to `Lazy($ => 2)`

Your code inspired me, so I tinkered with it until I wound up with this. I think you will be pleased ^_^ Bergi also suggested that `Lazy` should not re-evaluated its result. I handled that with a safe memoisation inside the `runLazy` method. Feedback on this would be appreciated <3

> **personal code style**
>
> As a convention, I write thunks as `$ => expr` instead of `() => expr`. When writing functional programs in JavaScript, you end up with a lot of `()`s, often times adjacent to other `()`s which can sometimes hurt readability. I think `Lazy($ => f())` reads (at least) slightly better than `Lazy(() => f())`. Since this is meant to be an educational site, I figure this is worth mentioning. I *feel* like small change helps with readability, but I also don't want to confuse anyone.
>
> For anyone that's stuck, feel free to substitute `()` for all `$` in the code below. Moving along now ...

```js
// data Lazy = Lazy (Unit -> a)
const Lazy = t => ({
  memo: undefined,
  // runLazy :: Lazy a -> Unit -> a
  runLazy () {
    return this.memo === undefined
      // console.log call just for demonstration purposes; remove as you wish
      ? (this.memo = t(), console.log('computed:', this.memo), this.memo)
      : this.memo
  },
  // chain :: Lazy a -> (a -> Lazy b) -> Lazy b
  chain (f) {
    return Lazy($ => f(this.runLazy()).runLazy())
  }
})

// Lazy.of :: a -> Lazy a
Lazy.of = x =>
  Lazy($ => x)
  
// repeat :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> Lazy a
const repeat = n => f => x =>
  n === 0
    ? Lazy.of(x)
    : Lazy.of(f(x)).chain(repeat (n-1) (f))

// m :: Lazy Number
const m = repeat (5) (x => x * 2) (1)

console.log('computations pending...')
// ...
console.log(m.runLazy()) // (1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2) => 32
console.log(m.runLazy()) // => 32
```

As for satisfying the other categories, here's some more method implementations for `Lazy`. I got hung up on the Monoid for `empty`, but maybe you or someone else has some ideas there !

I also saw that you derived `chain` from `f => join(map(f))` which is perfectly fine too

**Functor**

```
// map :: Lazy a -> (a -> b) -> Lazy b
map (f) {
  return Lazy($ => f(this.runLazy()))
}
```

**Applicative**

```
// apply :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
const apply = f => x => f (x)

// ap :: Lazy (a -> b) -> Lazy a -> Lazy b
ap (m) {
  return Lazy($ => apply (this.runLazy()) (m.runLazy()))
}
```

**Monad**

```
// Lazy.of :: a -> Lazy a
Lazy.of = x =>
  Lazy($ => x)

// chain :: Lazy a -> (a -> Lazy b) -> Lazy b
chain (f) {
  return Lazy($ => f(this.runLazy()).runLazy())
}

// join :: Lazy (Lazy a) -> Lazy a
join () {
  return Lazy($ => this.runLazy().runLazy())
}
```

**Monoid**

```
// empty
empty () {
  // unsure on this one
}

// concat :: (Monoid a) => Lazy a -> Lazy a -> Lazy a
concat (m) {
  return Lazy($ => this.runLazy().concat(m.runLazy()))
}
```

---

**open exploration**

This topic is very fun for me so I'm happy to discuss anything I've written about here or any other comments about the ideas presented in this question/answer. Let's have more fun!

Comment: If you want some more fun, try implementing `map`, `ap` and `join` without `runLazy`, only in terms of `.chain()` and `of()` :-)

Comment: `Lazy` is not a monoid. What you were doing in `concat` is implement `Monoid a => Monoid(Lazy a)`, speaking in Haskell terms. But I don't think that's really useful. (Edit: Hm, Haskell [*does* implement](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:1) `Monoid a => Monoid (Identity a)` and other similar stuff, so well...)

Comment: Bergi intriguing challenge. I'll try it tonight ^^

Comment: I believe `empty` would be `return Lazy($ => this.runLazy().empty())`

Comment: @4castle No. There's no `this` in arrow functions, and nothing you can `runLazy` on. `empty` needs to produce a value out of thin air. You can only write the monoid instance when you know what data type you're going to wrap - then you can use `Lazy.of(A.empty())`

Comment: "_Your monadic return (or of in this case) is also broken_" I've never made my peace with `of` in Javascript. As I understand the function, it is essentially required to prove the monad laws - please correct me, if I'm mistaken. In the end, it generates a value simply by using the constructor as well. It offers a bit of convenience in the `Lazy` case, though.

Comment: You have to pass the empty value explicitly to your `empty` method, since JS doesn't have type inference (I don't use the prototype system at all and therefore have to pass `concat` to the binary operation too). Is there a special reason that `empty` is a function?

Comment: @Bergi, fun exercise; [my results](https://repl.it/I4rU) - this has me thinking about the various ways to implement functional data structures and control flow in js